# Two Taylor Series for $-\sin(x)$ are Equal But One Doesn't Work?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

By taking the derivative of the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$, I got two different Taylor series for $-\sin(x)$ (one starts at $n=0$, and one at $n=1$).

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$
Graphically, these are the same, but the second series doesn't make sense to me. If you plug in $n=0$, you have to divide by $(-1)!$, which is undefined.

Can we still consider the second Taylor Series to be correct?

Comment: You can think of, more or less, \frac{1}{-1!} As $0$. It is in fact undefined, but look at what the gamma function does around $0$.

Comment: @RyanGoulden I'm sorry I haven't learned what a gamma function is. Is there anyway I can understand the question at hand without a gamma function?

Comment: Unfortunately, to my understanding, it would be hard to understand negative factorials without the gamma function. The gamma function extends the domain of the factorial function, and it is continuous (so in fact, we may evaluate $\frac{1}{2} !$). It has a fairly simple integral definition. If you look at the integral, it is clear that it diverges at specific values, namely, non-positive integers. In other words $(-1)! = \Gamma(0) = ∞$. I would recommend looking into it! The gamma function is really neat and an extremely important special function.

Comment: Without it, it would be hard (if possible at all) to talk about negative factorials in any sense. But I should imagine that your issue is resolved by saying that the 0-th term in the second sum vanishes.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you did something like this:
$$\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$
And differentiated it:
$$-\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}$$
You can spot the mistake if you write out the first few terms:
$$\frac{x^0}{0!}-\frac{x^2}{2!}-...$$
And you differentiated it like this:
$$0 \frac{x^{-1}}{0!}-2\frac{x}{2!}+...$$
And here is the mistake: You took $\frac{0}{0!}=\frac{1}{(-1)!}$. Of course, $(-1)!$ is not defined, but because of these cases, we can take $\frac{1}{n!}=0$ for negative $n$, just like having $0^0=1$.

Comment: Isn't a mistake that the derivative of $x^0$ is not $x^{-1}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes and no. The $(x^n)'=n x^{n-1}$ "works" for $n=0$ as well for $x \neq 0$, because $\frac{0}{x}=0 \forall x \neq 0$. But of course, saying that $(x^0)'=0$ is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $x^{2n}$ is $2n x^{2n-1}$.

That means that for $n=0$ it is **null**, and you shall cancel it (sum starting from $n=1$) before simplifying with the factorial at denominator.